# Terraform - Build Fails Non-existent AMI

Tags: terraform

I have the following code in Terraform. The issue is the image no longer exits and it's failing to build.

```
data "aws_ami" "ami_ai_demos" {
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-20200323"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }
  owners = ["099720109477"]
}
```

I could update `values` with the current image but do not want to rebuild the image. Is there anyway to work around this issue?

Comment: What do you mean with rebuild the image?

Comment: When I look at the list of ubuntu images on https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/ I no longer see 20200323. If update this URL     values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-20200323"] then won't Terraform want to create an new EC2 instance?

Comment: Also, the issue looks to be with the region. The image is available in us-east-1 but not us-east-2.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be rebuilding the image, rather recreating the instance. I wouldn't say it's an issue, it's basically forcing you to use a newer OS version which is for your benefit.

Answer (score 1):

It was most probably deprecated thus not searchable anymore. Just use direct ami ID for your region instead of filters.
https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/

[cloud-images.ubuntu.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FnXU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions. As my requirements are that the EC2 instance is not rebuilt, I will have to remove it from Terraform state. This makes sense as so long as Terraform see's it it'll want to act on the resource.

https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/state/rm

Answer (score 0):

The better option would be to use like this, as this will always pick up the latest image avalaible and your build will not fail.

```
data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
most_recent = true
  owners      = ["099720109477"]
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "root-device-type"
    values = ["ebs"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "architecture"
    values = ["x86_64"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Good call to change the filter. The issue now is it wants to update the instance but is blocked. I was told these instance cannot be rebuilt and now it's blocked because lifecycle is set to true.

Comment: I also considered a custom AMI. Had we have built a custom AMI this wouldn't be an issue.